# How to fix the type error arising from using sympy symbolic expressions

Tags: python, sympy

I'm creating a variable in terms of many sympy symbolic representations:

```
m,R,e,rho,V,C_L,c,Omega,psi,e,q_dot,p_dot,q,p=sym.symbols('m,R,e,rho,V,C_L,c,Omega,psi,e,q_dot,p_dot,q,p')
I_e = 1/3 * m *(R-e)**3
S_e = 1/2 * m * (R-e) **3
M_A = (rho*V**2*C_L*c*(R**2-e**2))/4

M_beta = (1/(I_e*Omega**2))*(M_A+(I_e+e*S_e)*Omega**2*(q_dot/Omega)*sym.cos*(psi)-\
                            (I_e+e*S_e)*Omega**2*(p_dot/Omega)*sym.sin(psi)-\
                             2*(I_e+e*S_e)*Omega**2*(q/Omega)*sym.sin(psi)-\
                             2*(I_e+e*S_e)*Omega**2*(p/Omega)*sym.cos(psi))
```

However, this error occurred and I don't know how to fix is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-86d345ec5696> in <module>
      6 M_beta = (1/(I_e*Omega**2))*(M_A+(I_e+e*S_e)*Omega**2*(q_dot/Omega)*sym.cos*(psi)-\
      7                             (I_e+e*S_e)*Omega**2*(p_dot/Omega)*sym.sin(psi)-\
----> 8                              2*(I_e+e*S_e)*Omega**2*(q/Omega)*sym.sin(psi)-\
      9                              2*(I_e+e*S_e)*Omega**2*(p/Omega)*sym.cos(psi))
     10 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\decorators.py in __sympifyit_wrapper(a, b)
     89                 if not hasattr(b, '_op_priority'):
     90                     b = sympify(b, strict=True)
---> 91                 return func(a, b)
     92             except SympifyError:
     93                 return retval

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\decorators.py in binary_op_wrapper(self, other)
    127                     if f is not None:
    128                         return f(self)
--> 129             return func(self, other)
    130         return binary_op_wrapper
    131     return priority_decorator

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\expr.py in __mul__(self, other)
    194     @call_highest_priority('__rmul__')
    195     def __mul__(self, other):
--> 196         return Mul(self, other)
    197 
    198     @_sympifyit('other', NotImplemented)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\operations.py in __new__(cls, *args, **options)
     45             return args[0]
     46 
---> 47         c_part, nc_part, order_symbols = cls.flatten(args)
     48         is_commutative = not nc_part
     49         obj = cls._from_args(c_part + nc_part, is_commutative)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sympy\core\mul.py in flatten(cls, seq)
    305                 #      e
    306                 # o = b
--> 307                 b, e = o.as_base_exp()
    308 
    309                 #  y

TypeError: as_base_exp() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

I my checked my code over and over again but still have no idea how to fix this. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: Since the error in a long multiline expression, you should evaluate individual terms till you find the one that's giving problem.  Apply some basic debugging skills!

Comment: Maybe `sym.cos*(psi)` should be `sym.cos(psi)`

Comment: problem is fixed now, I was being blind!

Comment: Also note that to avoid introducing pesky floats into sympy expressions, it is recommended to use something like `sym.S(1/3)` instead of `1/3`.  See [sympy gotchas and pitfalls](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html)